# Are 3rd party iOS/iPadOS apps able to access memory cards/USB flash memory?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ipados

At WWDC 2019, Apple announced that they are adding additional support for flash drives, memory cards, etc.

https://www.cnet.com/news/ipados-will-let-you-plug-flash-drives-memory-cards-into-your-ipad-wwdc/

Are 3rd party apps able to access the file system for "mounted" devices like SD cards, USB thumb drives, etc? Or is that support limited to Apple apps like Files and Photos?

If we *are* able to access the file system, is there a special API we need to use, or is it sufficient to just use the regular `NSFileManager` methods with the appropriate paths?

Answer (score 0):

If you have iOS13 than:

```
YES
```

If iOS12 and lower:

```
NO
```

Comment: Any details on how to accomplish this? What API we need to use? How to request access to the external device?